# How can you reverse an ArrayList in Java without creating a new list, only use add, remove and size?

Tags: java, arraylist

I understand that the collections.reverse method uses the swap function but I am trying to determine how to create that swap method essentially using only the add and remove methods.

I cannot create a new list either.

Pseudocode thoughts

```
add item at last index to front of list
delete last item
add second item to end of list
delete second item
add second last item to second index
delete second last item
```

and keep going like that?

I'd obviously need to put this into a for loop
I feel like this is really easy and I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: @tkruse There are `add` and `remove` methods that don't add to or remove from the end.

Comment: Check my answer, there is built-in method for that.

Comment: Is this an interview question? Or possibly for a class?

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 3):

Simple enough, there is a static method in Collections class reverse(), so just do:

```
Collections.reverse(yourListHere);
```

OK so I just read you can only use add and remove, check this:

```
package com.company;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,4));

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            lista.add(i, lista.remove(lista.size() - 1));
        }

        System.out.println(lista);

    }
}
```

Comment: Clearer still. So, the remove method returns the value removed, I take it.

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Comment: Or if you want to improve it still further, you can make the list run to `i < lista.size() - 1`, since the last iteration will simply remove the last element and then put it back exactly where it was.

Comment: @MTL-VRN You're right, even though one iteration won't mean a lot in this case, but it could if code inside the loop was more sophisticated. Good catch.

Comment: @MTL-VRN Why not use the diamond operator ?

Comment: @FairPlay because I had somehow never heard of that before today.  Upon looking it up, however, your code was fine as-is, and my edit was unnecessary.  TIL, that'll simplify my code a bit in the future.

Comment: @MTL-VRN Do make note that it's valid from JDK7, so it won't compile in older versions.

Comment: Collections.reverse returns nothing, so I do not understand how that helps here.

Comment: @AndroidAnton I'm not sure what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Object> list = getArraylist();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 1) {
    list.add(i, list.get(list.size() - 1));
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```

Simple enough.

Comment: Doesn't list.size() keep getting incremented every time you add to it?

Comment: @BobRodes It will increment to size of 7 then go back to 6 after element is removed, nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: @FairPlay Oh, now I see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReverseList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);

        int median = list.size()/2;
        for (int i = 0, j = list.size()-1; i < median; i++,j--) {
            swap(list, i, j);
        }

        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void swap(List<Integer> list, int leftPointerIndex, int rightPointerIndex) {
        int leftElement = list.get(leftPointerIndex);
        int rightElement  = list.get(rightPointerIndex);
        list.set(leftPointerIndex, rightElement);
        list.set(rightPointerIndex, leftElement);
    }

}
```